# Excel 2007 Connection String (xlsx)

Tags: c#, excel, xls, xlsx

Hello all I'm trying to pull from an Excel xlsx document but I keep getting an error "External table not in the expected format." Heres what I'm using as my connection string:

---

```
String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;'", filePath);

using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
            {
                    excelConnection.Open();
```

---

**filepath**- Is simply a string with the file path of my Excel Spreadsheet, which is pulled from a form upload control.

I get to the point of my code where I want to open the connection and it just errors out. But here's the kicker....I tried the same connection string on a **.XLS** file and it connected fine, even ran a query as expected. When I google the connection string I find that I'm using the same connection as everyone else just mine wont work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version MS Office are you using 2007/2010?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES'"
```

or this

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR=YES'"
```

Comment: Tried it...still no go

Comment: do you think it has something to do with my microsoft ACE?

Comment: I think not ... sure it is properly charging the variable "filePath"

Comment: Haha I actually took my first connection string from that site....I'm sure its the correct path because when i put an xls file from the same directory in the file upload control everything works and the data is successfully pulled.

Comment: maybe the file "xlsx" have problems. Sorry, I can not think otherwise, because from what I see the connexion string is correct. (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this macro enabled connection string:**

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsm;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES";
```

Comment: That was my first time trying with the macro enabled string, it still did not work though

Comment: There could be many reasons for this error; one of them is that the file is locked by another user, for example your file is on a shared drive and another user has the file opened, or the file was uploaded or created by another application and the application still has a lock on it, if this was a one time load then you just need to copy the file and load the copied version of the file.

Comment: You can also refer this link for information on this error: [msdn link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2459087)

Comment: Vishal thanks for the help, I have narrowed it down to the problem being something outside of my code. I cant  figure it out, I will just have to tell the app users to use .XLS only.